# Default value for public properties

Tags: c#, .net

I have a public property in some class. I want a default value -1 for this property without an private variable like _MyField(because too many properties in this class, i won't add them one by one).

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

[DefaultValueAttribute] is not working for this issue i think. Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE @ Aug 2015** Now we have C# 6!

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 100;

public string EasyToUse { get; } = "YES!";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have two options - you can set the property in the constructor of the object, or use a private field.

Personally, I feel the constructor is the best option, as it's clear to people reading your code what your intentions are for a fresh instance of your class.

`[DefaultValue]` is an attribute meant for use with visual designer functionality, and has no effect on your class logic.

Comment: No other way to make a default value? You know I really want an expression like this :(

public int MyAttr = -1 { get; set; }

Comment: Danny, that kinda defeats the purpose of automatic properties. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a `this.MyAttr = -1` assignment in the object's constructor.